# Displacement distribution Molecular Dynamics

Tags: computational-physics, software, data-analysis, molecular-dynamics

I have a file "traj.dat" with the trajectory of $N$ particles for $M$ frames separated by $\Delta M$ steps (with a time-step $\Delta t$). I often compute Mean Square Displacement (MSD) of the system for different lag times (following the algorithm explained in Wikipedia).

For two given times, $t_0$ and $t_1$,the value $MSD(t_0,t_1)$ is basically the second momentum of the displacement distribution between this times, $P(|\Delta r|,t_1-t_0)$, right?But I'm not sure about how I have to compute this distribution between two frames and over the time. I have computed distributions (as density distribution) for independence frames and average over all of them, but I'm confuse about the algorithm for this "dynamical" properties where you need differences between two frames

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `traj.dat` file contains $N$ rows corresponding to the $N$ particle trajectories (different initial conditions) and $M$ columns corresponding to each (equispaced) time step. Call this matrix $R$. The time-dependant displacement distribution $P(\Delta r, t)$ can be obtained by creating a histogram of the columns of $R$. For instance, let $t_i = i \Delta t$ where $i = 0,1,..., M-1$, then $P(\Delta r(t_i), t_i)$ is represented by `histogram(R[,i])` and the MSD could be computed as `MSD[i] = variance(R[,i])`.

As for the 'difference between two frames', I can only assume you are trying to identify the scaling properties of the process directly from the distribution. If the process is scale invariant, then

$$P(\Delta r, t) = \dfrac{1}{t^{\alpha}} P\left(\dfrac{\Delta r}{t^\alpha}\right)$$

and $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ is the scale (assuming constant speed!). Numerically, the above relation means that when we plot the two distributions at different times, e.g. $\frac{1}{t_i^\alpha}P(\Delta r(t_i)/t_i^\alpha)$ and $\frac{1}{t_j^\alpha}P(\Delta r(t_j)/t_j^\alpha)$, we will find the two densities superimposed and the value $2 \alpha$ is the scaling exponent in `MSD[i]`.